# Troubleshooting an MSATA drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery

I have a Microsoft Surface Pro 3 with a broken screen which I thought I'd use as some type of server at home.

It's MSATA drive doesn't seem to be working, however, there is no real reason for it to be broken given the fact that it wasn't damaged when the screen was damaged.

I've tried to connect the MSATA drive to an MSATA-to-USB adapter but the drive is not recognized in other computers.

Obviously the drive isn't recognized in the MSP3 either, but I just can't figure out as to why it's not recognized.

Is there any tool out there for troubleshooting drives that do not appear in Windows Disk Manager?

Maybe the drive as a USB device with the MSATA-to-USB adapter is recognized as a USB device but not as a drive, of which it could be troubleshooted with some specific software that can somehow still get access to the drive and analyze it?

What I'm trying to do is to just make sure that it's 100% broken before I buy I new one.

Comment: You have tried everything.

Comment: You can always try a mSATA to SATA III adapter but it sounds like the drive is dead

Comment: Is there any good sites on drive repair?
Maybe it's just a fried cap or a fried resistor that is the problem?

Comment: Your not going to be able to repair a SSD....

Comment: Never underestimate the power of a hacker. Give me the tools and the time and I'll make anything possible.